# visjs.org library : not time based x-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, vis.js

I'm using visJS to render charts.
I know how to create stackedbar chart butI am wondering how can I render a Graph2d graph whitch x-axis would not be time based and just categories like : 
[image]

Comment: it's called bar graph. There is an example [here](http://visjs.org/examples/graph2d/11_barsSideBySideGroups.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Graph2d isn't suitable for that, it's really built to show a time axis horizontally.